# Importar dataframe python a sql server management studio

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Holas buen dia!
Tengo dudas para conectar mi dataframe a una base de datos sql

1. ¿La base de datos tiene que estar creada a la hora de querer importar un dataframe?
2. ¿Tiene que haber una tabla ya creada dentro de una base de datos para ahi importar mi dataframe?

Estoy usando la libreria sqlalchemy ya que me guie de un codigo que vi pero queria saber para que es cada cosa asi que aqui les dejo mi codigo

```
import sqlalchemy

import pyodbc

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
"mssql+pyodbc:# a) esto que significa?
//blessing: # b) este debe ser el nombre de usuario de mi computadora
298845          # c) la contraseña del usuario que puse 
@(localdb)\DESKTOP-111BKJJBF  # d) el nombre del servidor de mi sql management studio
\dbseguros"   # e) el nombre de mi base de datos
,echo=False)  # f) esto no se que significa

df.to_sql('Table_1 - dbseguros' #aqui debe ir el nombre de la tabla de la base de datos o el
                                        #if_exists='append' ya la crea? 
, con=engine, 
if_exists='append')
```

y me arroja el siguiente error

```
DBAPIError:(pyodbc.Error) ('IM010', '[IM010] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] El 
nombre del origen de datos es demasiado largo (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/dbapi)
```

espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!!